# How can I get OfficeRuntime.Storage to work on Macs (so 2 open add-ins in different apps can exchange data)?

Tags: macos, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins, excel-web-addins

My add-in shares data between Excel and Word.
I'm trying to use OfficeRuntime.Storage with sharedRuntime to do this. It works great on Windows (where the Office version is supported), but I can't get it to fully work on Macs (it doesn't share data add-in to add-in).

I use OfficeRuntime.storage.setItem(key, value) and OfficeRuntime.storage.getItem(key) as referenced here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-runtime/officeruntime.storage?view=common-js

Both Excel and Word load the add-in from the same manifest (1 manifest ).

The Runtime has been added to the manifest for both Host sections to enable sharedRuntime

```
    <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <Runtimes>
                <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" />
        </Runtimes>
```

and

```
    <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <Runtimes>
            <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" />
        </Runtimes>
```

The add-ins do the following on both Windows and Macs:

- within the same add-in, getValue does successfully get setValue
- Closing the add-in just hides the add-in; opening it just unhides it (as is expected with SharedRuntime working)
- setValue adds the value to localStorage, like "_OfficeRuntime_Storage_myKey" (again implying that SharedRuntime is working)

In Windows, the Word add-in can successfully getValue the value set in the Excel add-in (at any time) and vice versa.

However, on Macs, the Word add-in does not see the value set in Excel (or vice versa). Also the other add-in cannot see localStorage[_OfficeRuntime_Storage_myKey] set in the other add-in, like it can on Windows.

I've tried on over a dozen Macs (with required Office versions), but none of them share data between add-ins.

So to me it looks like the 2 add-ins are running in the same runtime on Windows, but not Macs (even though it seems to think it is).

I do have the following action in both host sections in the manifest. Could that cause an issue?

```
    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
        <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
        <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
    </Action>
```

How can I get OfficeRuntime.Storage (or some other storage method) to work on Macs (so 2 open add-ins can exchange data)?

Comment: I'll try to get some help internally at MS. But note that 2 add-ins do not share the same runtime even on Windows. OfficeRuntime.Storage is a storage that is in Office, but outside the embedded runtime. That's why runtimes in Windows can share it.

Comment: @RickKirkham, any updates on how to locally share data between Excel and Word add-ins on Macs?

Comment: I'm still waiting for final confirmation, but I was told that sharing data across add-ins in this way is not supported and the fact that it works on Windows is actually a bug. It shouldn't work on any platform. Have you tried LocalStorage?

Comment: Yes, localStorage, indexedDB, and BroadcastChannel all sometimes do work on Windows (but not on modern Macs). I assumed OfficeRuntime.Storage was the most reliable/official method, so I may need to change my approach. I have many customers that want me to figure this out, so their data doesn't have to travel through a server.

Answer (score 1):

The shared runtime is designed for using in the same add-in, not between add-ins like it sounds from its name. The shared runtime is not related to storage in any way.

The [OfficeRuntime.Storage interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-runtime/officeruntime.storage?view=common-js) has the following description:

```
Storage limit is 10 MB per domain, which may be shared by multiple add-ins.
```

So, that sounds like an issue on the MacOS. In that case I'd suggest filing an issue on the [OfficeJS](https://github.com/officedev/office-js/issues) repo in github.

Comment: Here is the github issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2928